# Qt Mouse Event Receiving issue

Tags: c++, qt

This might seem as too simple question, but I couldn't find the answer for too long, so I've decided to ask a question here.
I have a class derived from `QFrame`. It contains two buttons. 
Issue: When I set a parent to those buttons as "this" they do show up but they have no reaction to the mouse. When I set as parent parent of my `QFrame` it works:

When:

```
m_btnCompile = new ApproxGUIMenuButton(this);
m_btnSettings = new ApproxGUIMenuButton(this);
```

Doesn't work

When:

```
m_btnCompile = new ApproxGUIMenuButton(parentWidget());
m_btnSettings = new ApproxGUIMenuButton(parentWidget());
```

Works

Second option isn't solution for me because I need buttons to be in local coordinate system.
Parent is generated by QDesigner. I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 if it's important. What do I need to do? Please, help.

Comment: Why don't you add buttons to a layout?

Comment: Because I want to place my buttons as I want which I assume is not as that simple with layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved but I still don't know a reason. I've added new member derived from QWidget and inside it set it as parent to those buttons and it worked.